# Restore deleted Calendar Storage app

Tags: lineageos, calendar

The Calendar Storage app is missing and it's preventing me from using the stock calendar app or any custom calendar app. I've tried re-installing the stock calendar from apkmirror.com, but it immediatly closes when I try to open it. When I try to open Business Calendar for the first time, it asks for permission to access my calendar and then says:

> "Calendar Storage disable
> Your calendars and events can't be displayed because Calenda storage has been disabled on your device.
> Turn Calendar storage back on in Settings to use this app."

There is an "Enable in Settings" button which takes me to an App Info page for Calendar Storage. However, the Permissions section is grayed out and it claims to not be disabled. Also, Calendar Storage isn't listed in Settings > Apps like it is on my other Android phone.

I probably accidently deleted it while de-bloating the phone with the "Uninstall System Apps" app. I intended to remove the stock calendar since I wanted to use business calendar instead. I'm running Lineage OS 19 (Android version 12) and am rooted. I'm hoping to avoid re-installing to fix this issue. I realize the calendar data is probably unrecoverable, but that isn't important.

I've tried finding APKs for Calendar Storage and installing them, but haven't found one that worked yet:

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/lineageos/calendar-storage-2/calendar-storage-2-11-release/calendar-storage-11-2-android-apk-download/download/
This one is labeled for Android 11+, but fails to install with, "App not installed as package appears to be invalid".
When I try to install it with APK Mirror Installer, it fails with "The new package has an older version code than the currently installed package".

I've also tried using Titanium Backup to backup an older phone's (Lineage OS, Android 9) Calendar Storage app and restore it on the new phone, but the restore process hangs indefinitely.

Besides the question of how to fix this problem, I'm wondering if anyone with Lineage OS 19 could send the current version of the Calendar Storage APK, as I can't seem to find a copy online.

Phone Information: Google Pixel 3a XL

ROM:Lineage 19.1 2022-05-07 Bonito.
Installed using lineage-19.1-20220507-recovery-bonito.img ([source](https://download.lineageos.org/bonito))

Android 12.1

Comment: So you are using LineageOS + root and using root permissions you have deleted an important APK that is now missing, correct? Because otherwise this would be a defect of the sued ROM. Unfortunately you don't tell any details about phone model, used Android version and used ROM (official, unofficial -> what ROM?).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't believe this is a defect of the ROM. I can't say be 100% certain when Calendar Storage disappeared or if it was ever there, but the most likely explanation is that I deleted it when deleting the Lineage stock calendar. I added phone and ROM information to my question.